# Xamarin.Forms - Cross-platform images on top of each other

Tags: mobile, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a simple question with (in my opinion) a too difficult solution. I'd like to have a "main" image and some other "small" image on top of it in the right upper corner. Something like the iOS homescreen buttons with notifications:

[image: iOS home-screen buttons with notifications]

Does anyone know how to do something like this in a **Xamarin.Forms** way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved by using a grid with every cell having a `RelativeLayout`. Each square receives two children: a button and an image. The image is small and will move to the right-top because of the constraint `RelativeToParent`:

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout();
relativeLayout.Children.Add(button,
                       Constraint.Constant(0), 
                       Constraint.Constant(0));
relativeLayout.Children.Add(image, 
                       Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
                       {
                           return parent.Width - 40;
                       }), 
                       Constraint.Constant(0));
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that this can be accomplished with AbsoluteLayout: http://iosapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=T%3AXamarin.Forms.AbsoluteLayout.

You can grab a sample of it here: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/FormsGallery/FormsGallery/FormsGallery/AbsoluteLayoutDemoPage.cs